# Apache Spark broadcast variable giving errors with mappartitions

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to python and Spark and here I am trying broadcast spark Rtree Index. When I try to broadcasted index with mapPartitions function it errors out with following errors

on Windows:

File "avlClass.py", line 42, in avlFileLine

```
for j in bv.intersection([x_meters-buffer_size,y_meters-buffer_size,x_meters
buffer_size,y_meters+buffer_size]):
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\site-packages\rtree\index.py", line 440, in in
tersection p_mins, p_maxs = self.get_coordinate_pointers(coordinates)
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\site-packages\rtree\index.py", line 294, in ge
t_coordinate_pointers
dimension = self.properties.dimension
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\site-packages\rtree\index.py", line 883, in ge
t_dimension
return core.rt.IndexProperty_GetDimension(self.handle)
indowsError: exception: access violation reading 0x00000004
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala
166)
```

In Linux:

```
ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:387)
```

file : avlClass.py

```
import fiona
from shapely.geometry import shape,Point, LineString, Polygon
from shapely.ops import transform
from rtree import index
from numpy import math
import os
import pyproj
from functools import partial
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

class avlClass(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name

    def create_index(self):
        # Read the ESRI Shape File
        shapeFileName='C:\\shapefiles\\Road.shp'
        polygons= [ pol for pol in fiona.open(shapeFileName,'r') ]
        p=index.Property()
        p.dimension=2
        self_idx=index.Index(property=p)
        # Create Index Entries
        for pos,features in enumerate(polygons):
           self_idx.insert(pos,LineString(features['geometry']  ['coordinates']).bounds )
        return self_idx


    def avlFileLine(self,iter,bv):
      for line in iter:
            splits =line.split(',')
            lat= float(splits[2])
            long= float(splits[3])
            print  lat,long
            x='No'

            # Test the index from broadcast Variable bv
           buffer_size=10
            x_meters=-9511983.32151
            y_meters=4554613.80307
            for j in bv.intersection([x_meters-buffer_size,y_meters-buffer_size,x_meters+buffer_size,y_meters+buffer_size]):
                x= "FOUND"

            yield lat,long,heading_radians,x
```

File : avlSpark.py

```
import fiona
from shapely.geometry import shape,Point, LineString, Polygon
from shapely.ops import transform
from rtree import index
from numpy import math
import os
import pyproj
from functools import partial
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from avlClass import avlClass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    conf = SparkConf().setAppName('AVL_Spark_Job')
    conf = SparkConf().setMaster('local[*]')
    sc= SparkContext(conf=conf)

    sc.addPyFile("avlClass.py")
    test_avlClass=avlClass("Test")

    print test_avlClass.name
    idx= test_avlClass.create_index()

    # Test the created index
    buffer_size=10
    x_meters=-9511983.32151
    y_meters=4554613.80307
    for j in idx.intersection([x_meters-buffer_size,y_meters-buffer_size,x_meters+buffer_size,y_meters+buffer_size]):
         print "FOUND"  # Index Worked

    # broadcast Index for Partitions
    idx2=sc.broadcast(idx)



    FileName='c:\\test\\file1.txt'
    avlFile=sc.textFile(FileName).mapPartitions(lambda line: test_avlClass.avlFileLine(line,idx2.value))
    for line in avlFile.take(10):
     print line
```

Answer (score 0):

What I am seeing is you are creating a broadcast var:

```
# broadcast Index for Partitions
idx2=sc.broadcast(idx)
```

but then passing its .value into AvlFileLine:

```
avlFile=sc.textFile(FileName).mapPartitions(lambda line: test_avlClass.avlFileLine(line,idx2.value))
```

but neither idx or idx2 are RDDs. idx2, as a broadcast variable, [will take on whatever class idx is. (I actually asked this question based on your question :)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34864751/apache-spark-broadcast-variables-are-type-broadcast-not-a-rdd)

You are still treating that passed parameter as a broadcast var, BUT then trying to treat it like an RDD, [presumably a PythonRDD](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.1/api/python/pyspark.rdd.RDD-class.html) [which as noted, it's not.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34864751/apache-spark-broadcast-variables-are-type-broadcast-not-a-rdd) A broadcast variable is not an RDD, it's just whatever type you assign to it. Further you are passing its value (using `.value()`)into AVLFileLine.

**So when you call intersection() on it, it blows up.** I am surprised it doesn't blow up more nicely but I work in Java where the compiler would catch this, I am assuming in Python the interpreter just happily runs along until it hits a bad memory location and you get that ugly error message :)

I think the best approach is to rethink your code from the start, it's just not the right use of Spark. I don't know your specific application that well, so my best guess is that you need to abandon intersection() and instead [look again at the RDD programming guide part of the Spark docs for Python](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#passing-functions-to-spark). Find a way to apply your `value` in `idx2` to `avlfile`, which IS a RDD. You need to avoid any for loops inside the passed function, Spark is doing the "for" loop for you by applying whatever function you pass to each element of the RDD. Remember the result will be another RDD.

In **psuedo-Java** code it would look like:

```
 SomeArray theArray = avlfile.map({declare inline or call function}).collect(<if the RDD is not too big for collect>)
```

I hope that helps, if you have not yet done so, [a great book is Learning Spark by O'Reilly](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449358624) and [the sample code for the book](https://github.com/databricks/learning-spark), it's the next step from [the Apache Spark Docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/). Learning Spark can be rented for under $10, in my case I get it free through Safari Books as a university student.

Writing Spark programs has a steep learning curve if you are not used to thinking in terms of functional programming, I am not that far ahead of you and IMHO you are just not quite understanding the Spark programming model yet. I hope this all helps.

---

Also as noted in the original edit of this answer your calls to SparkConf are wrong, [I had to go back a ways in the docs (.9)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.1/python-programming-guide.html) to find examples but you want something like this:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
conf = (SparkConf()
         .setMaster("local")
         .setAppName("My app")
         .set("spark.executor.memory", "1g"))
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
```

From the section on standalone programs ... right now I believe your second assignment to conf overwrites the first one.

---

SUMMARY: I don't understand that you would call RDD functions on a [broadcast variable, a broadcast variable is NOT an RDD but simply a data structure like a global that is read](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables) (and not written to) by all the workers. [Per the Broadcast class in Scala](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast)

[From the docs on Broadcast Variables](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables):

```
>>> broadcastVar = sc.broadcast([1, 2, 3])
<pyspark.broadcast.Broadcast object at 0x102789f10>

>>> broadcastVar.value
[1, 2, 3]
```

It looks to me like calling intersection() on bv (which is not an RDD) doesn't make sense.

Comment: 1.  IDX2.value is being passed as parameter(bv) to map function in the following like File=sc.textFile(FileName).mapPartitions(lambda line: test_avlClass.avlFileLine(line,idx2.value))

Comment: I am just seeing this on a tablet, will be at my computer later, but typically you would edit your question to add this :) And I see you passing idx2.value into avlFileLine but don't see where it's actually declared and assigned a value.

Comment: 3. erros in index.py is from RTree module that I have download. Before writing this for spark I tried in python and it worked in python.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. I am out of options.

Comment: I gave my answer a pretty thorough revamp, won't have more time until a few hours from now and probably don't have any better answers -- good luck! Thanks for posting the info I asked for :)

Comment: Also note since you are running Spark in local[] mode we are not getting into any issues of Spark distributing your code across a cluster, that's a whole different set of concerns